# Making Remotely Connected ubuntu server as GUI enabled

Tags: server, remote-desktop, remote-access

I am trying to connect to a remote server in cloud hosting service using remote desktop client application. Actually, the remote server is a server edition. I need it as GUI enabled like an Ubuntu desktop edition so that it will be user friendly. So I have installed Ubuntu-desktop using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

I'm able to connect to the server via putty SSH client. In putty we can run in command line mode only. I want to run the server in GUI mode. I can't access the server as GUI enabled in remote desktop client. Mine is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The remote server is also Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

What shall I do now?

Answer (score 1):

**NX Free Edition for Linux**

An enterprise-class multi-platform solution for remote access and virtual desktop delivery.

http://www.nomachine.com/select-package.php?os=linux&id=1

**DEB version**

Download the DEBs

Change your working directory to the location where you saved the package and install it by running from a console:

```
  $ sudo dpkg -i nxclient_3.5.0-7_i386.deb
  $ sudo dpkg -i nxnode_3.5.0-9_i386.deb
  $ sudo dpkg -i nxserver_3.5.0-11_i386.deb
```

If you don't have the sudo utility installed, log on as superuser ("root") and run the commands without sudo.

Note: click [here](http://www.nomachine.com/installation.php) for detailed instructions on how to install the NX Client, NX Node and NX Server packages. 
The NX service can be controlled by the command

`/usr/NX/bin/nxserver --status|--start|--stop|--restart`.

Additional commands are available to configure the server. Try

```
/usr/NX/bin/nxserver --help
```

for more information.

Please, don't forget to download and read the NX Server Administrator's Guide available [here](http://www.nomachine.com/documentation/admin-guide.php).

Comment: Thank you,

Your suggestion was realy helpful.

I've installed NX client,Server,Node in the remote server and installed NX client in the client side.Then i tried to configure the NX Server.When i run ./nxserver --status,it has to show the status as running.But it shows nothing.I tried to add a new user also using command sudo ./nxserver --useradd username --administrator and Now it has ask for password but it didn't.Whenever I use ./nxserver --(option) ,there is no effect for it.

What is the cause for this problem? What shall i do now?

Please help..

Thanks

Comment: As i remember (having a long time to use nx) you have nothing to configure to NX server. Just go to the client side and run NX client to connect to remote server (running NX Server) with its ip and port 22, with the user name and password of the remote server.

Comment: Hi..

When i try to open NX client wizard,it is showing nxclient: cannot connect to X server

what shall i do now?

Thanks in advance........

Comment: You may have not start the NX server service after installing. See my answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for this scenario would be to **use the xRDP software package**. By installing the xRDP package on the Ubuntu server, you will be able to connect to your server using remote desktop client (microsoft of linux rdp client)

if you use xRDP with recent version of Ubuntu, you have some limitations : Gnome 3 and Unity desktop are not supported and you will have no desktop available when remoting to your Linux server.   You need to install an alternate desktop (mate-desktop) and tell your system to use this desktop when performing remote session

Step by step instructions can be found [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=6046) if you are running recent Ubuntu version (version 14.10 or later)